# create element in js then apply style in another css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, createelement

```
const produits=document.getElementById("produit");
let firstDiv = document.createElement("div");
produits.appendChild(firstDiv);
let secondDiv=document.createElement("div");
firstDiv.appendChild(secondDiv);
secondDiv.setAttribute("className","deux");
```

i created element in js then gave it classname (deux) then called it in .css file (.deux) and tried applying style on it in the file but it didn't work even though both files're connected to html file

Comment: do you use vanilla js?

Comment: yes i'm still learning

Comment: try setAttribute("class","deux");

Answer (score 0):

Your error is quite simple actually. You set the attribute `className` instead of just using just `class`.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rpuyL5c/1/) with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

To add a class in JS when creating an element, do like this :

```
let secondDiv=document.createElement("div");
firstDiv.appendChild(secondDiv);
secondDiv.classList.add("deux");
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This file index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Make element using JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="produit"></div>
    
    <script>
        const produits=document.getElementById("produit");
        let firstDiv = document.createElement("div");
        produits.appendChild(firstDiv);
        let secondDiv=document.createElement("div");
        secondDiv.innerHTML = "This content class deux"
        firstDiv.appendChild(secondDiv);
        secondDiv.setAttribute("class","deux");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This file style.css

```
.deux{
    color: red;
}
```

Your code is only wrong when setting the class attribute in the second div, change **className** to **class**